# Consume WCF (WSDL) in .NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, wsdl, .net-5

I'm trying to get a WCF client for the following URL (https://api.mbeonline.es/ws/e-link.wsdl) which successfully generates a service reference correctly.

That said when I get to compile the project I a bunch of errors, all being the same though within the auto-generated code file:

```
Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'XXXX.System'
```

Which is weird. Previously I added the package `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` which I read is necessary in order to get the dependency `System.ServiceModel` sorted but still I'm not able to get the solution to compile and therefore I cannot use the service reference. Any ideas of what am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Actually I found what the problem was. Inside some of the generated classes there was a conflict because there was an element called System which was causing the error / conflict with the actual full namespace provided in some of the attributes System.Xml.... all I did was replacing the full namespace and put an using statement with the namespace at the top of the file. All errors gone!

Comment: You can write an answer and accept it as an answer to help people who have the same problem as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did contact Visual Studio Support for that issue and that suggesstet the following solution:

The compilation error is due to that the generated code class contains property named "System", it conflicts with the global "System" namespace. You can try to add "global::" keyword to point to the correct referenced .NET type to avoid this confliction. For example,
replace:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
```

with:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=global::System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue is the conflict between the generated code and it's attributes and the actual naming of the properties within the DataContract itself. Thus for example you could have a property called `System` and the attribute `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]` of the actual class.

In order to get around it, I did import the namespace: `using System.Xml.Schema;` and that way I avoided any conflict with properties called XmlSchemaForm which is very unlikely. In fact, and this is my personal view on this, the generation tool should do that automatically since a "System" property is relatively common to have and could cause issues like that.